# Is there any maximum limit for ActionProducer.MaxActionTime in Jemmy lib?

Tags: java, timeout, jemmy

As it is described on http://wiki.netbeans.org/Jemmy_Operators_Environment default time for `ActionProducer.MaxActionTime` is 10000 ms.

I need to increase it to 120000 ms and use next code:

```
JemmyProperties.setCurrentTimeout("ActionProducer.MaxActionTime", 120000);
```

And when the code is run under debugging mode the value is 120000:

[image]

but still I've got the next error:

> "Menu pushing: (JMenuItem with text "Modules", JMenuItem with text
>   "Corporate entity") (ActionProducer.MaxActionTime)" action has not been
>   produced in 60005 milliseconds

Is 60000 ms a maximum value for `ActionProducer.MaxActionTime`?

**UPDATE:**

Every instance of a class implementing `org.netbeans.jemmy.Timeoutable` can have its own timeout values, so I checked timeout of instance that generates error

```
menuBar.getTimeouts().getTimeout("ActionProducer.MaxActionTime")
```

but the result was the same - it is 120000 seconds and still failing at 60000 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that error message states `(ActionProducer.MaxActionTime)" action has not been produced in...`, there is another timout that rules this action time:

> JMenuOperator.PushMenuTimeout

Even if I set:

```
JemmyProperties.setCurrentTimeout("JMenuOperator.PushMenuTimeout", 50);
```

The error is:

> "Menu pushing: (JMenuItem with text "Modules", JMenuItem with text
>   "Corporate entity") (ActionProducer.MaxActionTime)" action has not been
>   produced in 51 milliseconds

So do not belive Jemmy log messages and try to find the right timeout.